# Trying to get dictionary values from a list of key index

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dynamic

I have a dictionary of lists:

> > > dic = {0:[[3, 3], [2,3]], 1:[[2, 2],[2, 5]]}

Im trying to pull values by index:

> > > dic[0][1][0]
> > > 2

I have a list of the strings of the indexes I want:

x = ['[0][1][0]', '[1][1][1]']

Is there a way to call the index by the string?

dic[x[0]]

Answer (score 0):

Barebones (non-pythonic) approach:

```
for i in x:
    a = int(i.split('][')[0].split('[')[1])
    b = int(i.split('][')[1])
    c = int(i.split('][')[2].split(']')[0])
    print(dic[a][b][c])
```